# Refreshing the ElasticSearch index from RDBMS using Spring Data

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have the following setup :

- Mysql RDBMS server
- Elastic Search Server

My requirement is to copy data periodically from MYSQL RDBMS and update Elastic server with it.Currently i am following the approach below :

- A Batch Job which reads all data from MYSQL using Spring Data Jpa
- It then pushes all data to elastic server using spring data elastic

This approach is very cumbersome and not efficient.Is there a way where i can read only the updated values using spring data and update the index accordingly in elastic.

Using jdbc-river etc is not an option for me as the application uses Spring data elastic to get data and search over elastic search,with jdbc-river it will not be able to function properly i think.

Comment: How about using the [Logstash JDBC plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html), it's been created just for that purpose.

Comment: Let me look at it,seems useful,since river has been deprecated this seems to be the best option

Comment: Definitely the best option, I concur ;)