# How to use ElasticSearch in spring boot having JPA in application, can I have to fetch records from table and put it in a index in elasticsearch?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, search, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am going to create the spring boot application having JPA for database operations and I have to provide the search engine (search for only data(like module links, documents along with small description) inside my web application) using Elastic search.

My question is to:

- Can I have to search the text around the tables inside my database
  and the put it in Index of elasticsearch, If Yes then when and how?
- what is the best way for fast search?

Please suggest the strategy and if any one know the example from end to end(from backend to UI) like this kind of application, please provide the demo.

I had refered the this post [Spring Boot + Spring Data JPA + Spring Data ElasticSearch: elastic doesn't return any results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43201437/spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-spring-data-elasticsearch-elastic-doesnt-retur?rq=1)
but its not the full code, if I will get full POC with that I can understand it I was doing something similar

Answer (score 2):

**For any insert/update:**

1. First fire a DB insert/update call. Wait for it to complete.
2. Fire an insert/update into Elasticsearch call in Async way using REST API.

**For any Search:**

1. Fire every search call to ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 1):

Mmm, 
May be you can use Logstash (It's an element of elasticsearch stack)
In a project, years ago, I used Logstash to migrate mysql databases to elasticsearch

I think that may be the best way is: 
Persist elements in transactions, this elements will be availables to search.

The best way to search? Can you be more specific?

Comment: best way for fast search means, If I fetch the data from the database and convert it to java pojo object then I insert it in index of elasticsearch, this all process will take too much time.

Comment: .Ok, I think that may be this can help you.

https://codeshare.co.uk/blog/how-to-copy-sql-server-data-to-elasticsearch-using-logstash/